# Unable to find Windows Docker Jenkins admin password

Tags: windows, docker, jenkins

I ran docker jenkins image on my Windows using this command from command prompt:

```
F:\Docker\Jenkins>docker run -v "F:\Docker\Jenkins":/var/jenkins_home -p 8081:8080 -p 50001:50000 jenkins/jenkins
```

The docker jenkins started fine & i then closed the command prompt without saving the output.

I am able to access the jenkins console using : http://localhost:8081/login?from=%2F

However, it is asking me for the admin password which I am not able to find.

Output below:

> Unlock Jenkins
>   To ensure Jenkins is securely set up by the administrator, a password has been written to the log (not sure where to find it?) and this file on the server:
>
> /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
>
> Please copy the password from either location and paste it below.

Below are the queries I have.

Question 1: How can I login in interactive mode to this running container so i can view the password from this file: /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword

I don't want to stop and run in interactive mode but would like to interact with the running containers directly.

Question 2: I get the below error running this command.

```
F:\Docker\Jenkins>docker run -it "F:\Docker\Jenkins":/var/jenkins_home -p 8082:8080 -p 50002:50000 jenkins/jenkins
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I also tried -i -t but same error. Any suggestions there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to login into docker machine.
The file is under `F:\Docker\Jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword`

`-v "F:\Docker\Jenkins":/var/jenkins_home` - it's bind mount a volume between docker disc and your disc on windows

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: How can I login in interactive mode to this running container so i can view the password from this file: /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword

**A:**

1. Use `docker ps` to find the container name, say `my_jenkins` for example.
2. Then Use `docker exec -it my_jenkins /bin/bash` to enter the container, then you can find the password.

> Question 2: I get the below error running this command.

**A:**

```
docker run -it -v "F:\Docker\Jenkins":/var/jenkins_home -p 8082:8080 -p 50002:50000 jenkins/jenkins
```

You miss `-v` for mount.